# What's the base of this logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I'm reading a scientific paper and an equation of the following form appears:

x = y log (z).

I know what y and z are in my own data set. How do I solve for x?

I'm used to logarithms of the form log<sub>2</sub>8, and then I can work out that the base is 2 and hence the answer is 3. How can I go about working out this unfamiliar (to me) form of logarithm? What's the base?

Edit: May as well provide a link to the paper. It's [here](https://webfiles.uci.edu/mdlee/LeeDanileiko2014.pdf), and the relevant part is on p264.

Comment: An unspecified base is 10. so it would be $y log_{10}(z)$

Comment: An unspecified base is also quite often $e$.

Comment: That would be denoted $ln$ wouldn't it?

Comment: In an undergraduate American algebra textbook, yes. In a scientific or mathematical paper, unspecified log can be $e$ or even $2$, even though $\ln$ and $\text{lg}$ are standard elsewhere.

Comment: @Stretch Maniac - Not necessarily. In information theory an unspecified base is usually 2, not 10.

Comment: I guess the paper is under specified unless given more information.

Comment: I just edited the post to provide a link to the paper just in case I am misreading it.

Comment: Since it's log-odds, the best guess seems to be $e$. It also looks like there is a parameter scaling the log-odds so that it doesn't matter what base is used. The wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit supports multiple possibilities (including 2). http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/glossary/?q=node/272 supports $e$ as standard for log-odds. Also, with $e$ as base, log-odds is the inverse of the logistic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper doesn't explicitly mention a base, but later on there's a reference to exponentiation, which indicates that the base is *e*.